# What does $||XY||_1$ mean?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have a question about the notation used in this problem **please dont solve the problem for me**.

> Show that $||XY||_1=||X||_1||Y||_1$ for independent r.vs $X$ and $Y$. Show further that if $X$ and $Y$ are also integrable, then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$

I don't understand what the difference between $||X||_1$ and $E(|X|)$. I assume we're talking about the $L^1(\mathbb{P})$ norm? But then $$||X||_1=\int_\Omega |X(\omega)|d\mathbb{P}(\omega)=E(|X|) $$
So if this is finite, then $E(X)$ exists therefore it is integrable already (so why "also"?) Therefore the first "show that" would follow from the second

Answer (score 2):

Under independence $||XY||_1=||X||_1||Y||_1$ holds even if $E|X|$ or $E|Y|$ is infinity (by Tonelli's Theorem). But $E(XY)=(EX)(EY)$ holds if the expectations are finite.